# How to represent in a slide professionally an algorithm?

Tags: presentation

I am preparing a slide presentation and I have to present a simple algorithm. Which is the best scheme that can easily understood and at the same time well accepted in academia?

Comment: Is this algorithm something new? Something unexpected? Long or short implementation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the audience, of course. But a slide full of code is probably not the best solution. I'll assume you can use a few slides, not just a single one.

A high level description of the purpose of the code might come first. What problem is it trying to solve. What competing algorithms are known.

A high level pseudo-code presentation might be next. It probably needn't be executable pseudocode but [Dijkstra's guarded command language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language) is also possible (and executable).

Somewhere you will want to mention the efficiency of the code, perhaps compared to competing algorithms. This might possibly be in the first slide.

Don't make the presentation so long that questions aren't possible.

But, for most purposes it probably isn't necessary to present the full code, especially in a modern language that is known by, perhaps, only a subset of the audience. The details required by the language itself won't be especially helpful to understanding the algorithm.